# Create Xml by using Php?

Tags: php, xml, dom

**I want to create this type of xml by using php  give me some suggestion**
can anyone correct this php code that i am not able to create a hierarchy.
i am taking input from html form (text box)

output is :-

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <model>4.0.0</model>

 <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>TODO</name>
            <url>TODO</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    </project>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

php code:-

```html
$xmlns = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$project = $document
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'project'));
$project->setAttributeNS(
  
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',  
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'
);

$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'url'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text5));


$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'licenses')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'license')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'url')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text6));
   ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'name')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text7));
 

$document->save("d.xml");

?>
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)

Comment: @ramobrero:- i want to create xml file from php . i am able to create a this part ('<model>4.0.0</model>') but how to write information inside project tag ... for ex:- xmlns="htttp: .... till............xsd>

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports the [DOM 3 Api](http://php.net/dom). You create nodes and append them to the document.

The XML in your question uses a namespace, so you have to create nodes for this namespace (use the *NS variants of the methods). This adds namespace definitions as needed.

```
$xmlns = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$project = $document
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'project'));
$project->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',  
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'
);
$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'model'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('4.0.0'));

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Comment: ThW:- Thanks for help. It is working .. Can you tell me topic Name which are helpful for me .. so that i can learn those topic

Comment: I linked the PHP Manual DOM pages. DOM is an W3C standard, you will find a lot of documentation about it and here are implementations for about any language. If you work with DOM in PHP read about XPath (`DOMXPath::evaluate()`). If you run into memory problems, check out the XMLReader/XMLWriter Apis.